# Setting SSH keys on Windows 10 OpenSSH server

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, permissions, openssh

I've set up OpenSSH on various flavors of Linux tons of times.  But I can't for the life of me get it functioning correctly on windows.

There seem to be two sides to the issue.  The permissions and the key used by `sshd`/`ssh-agent`.

**Permissions**

Every page I read has a different answer for the correct permissions.  Some work, and sometimes the program complains about them.

From what I understand the keys should all be owned by `SYSTEM`, with read access for `NT SERVICE\sshd` and Full Control for `Administrators` and `SYSTEM`?  (As I understand `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` represent root in Windows).  I read in the documentation that the read access is only necessary if not using `ssh-add`/`ssh-agent`.  I also configured the same permissions for the `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and added the `.pub` the Ed25519 key which is the one I'm using to try and connect, though I've also tried it with my own generated RSA key.

With the permissions set this way the program doesn't complain when adding keys to the agent or running the daemon.  The only option I changed in `sshd_config` is the `ListenAddress` which was binding to 0.0.0.0, I set it to the machines local IP as SSH will only be used locally.

**Keys**

When I run `sshd.exe` with the `-d` option, I notice it importing the 4 default keys from `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh`.  When I added the `ed25519.pub` key to `authorized_keys` it was followed by `HOSTNAME@workstation@HOSTNAME`, `HOSTNAME` being my PC's hostname.  Normally I would expected to see `user@host`.  I tried creating my own key and adding it but when I run `sshd.exe -d` it never seems to use anything other than the default keys.

In the end, I'm unable to connect to the OpenSSH server, and the logs in `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh/Logs` only seem to show the server starting.  To sum up my questions: What are the correct permissions for the key files and `authorized_hosts`?  Does the annotation in `authorized_keys` being wrong make a difference?  Should I be adding all of the default keys `.pub`'s into `authorized_hosts`?  And last, what does `sshd` mean when it mentions those keys during startup (see log)?  Shouldn't my own generated key just work as long as I add it to `authorized_hosts`?

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:and12LVkEqyXJ2gr0SxFEQObaSFF+Czlcnx2uFjZaJQ
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:waeLdy4Sm3NT+zbwEMIhbfl8TLe6WeQ0MuZE07CzFQU
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:G8/7y/04cSE3EezTrcmpK4lRmJ5f5I/CDPcHaPzsv4o
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Jvn9UjsbdzH54L/yvGYGfCzJQVIMiIWL5RETbaL2ACA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 192.168.1.144.
Server listening on 192.168.1.144 port 22.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to mix *server hosts keys* and your *account public keys*.

---

*Server host keys* are generated by Win32-OpenSSH in `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh` on its first start. They are also given correct permissions, no need to modify them. These are the keys you see loaded as "private host key" in your log. That also indicates they have the correct permissions (otherwise they won't load).

---

Your *account public keys* go to `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/authorized_keys` (or to `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys` for Administrator accounts). That file must have write access only for the account to which they belong.

The `authorized_keys` file should contain public key part of your *account key pair*. That's no way related to `.pub` files from `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh`.

A comment in the `authorized_keys` file does not matter at all.

Keys from `authorized_keys` file are not loaded when the server starts. They are loaded only, when you try to log in.

See also my guides to:

- [Setting up SSH public key authentication on Win32-OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#key_authentication)
- [Understanding SSH Key Pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys)

Answer (score 42):

Note that if you are setting up keys for an administrator user, putting the public key to `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/authorized_keys` will not work. You must append the public key to `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys` instead.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#authorizedkeysfile)

And you have to set permission with this script run in powershell admin:

```
$acl = Get-Acl C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)
$administratorsRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("Administrators","FullControl","Allow")
$systemRule = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("SYSTEM","FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($administratorsRule)
$acl.SetAccessRule($systemRule)
$acl | Set-Acl
```

Comment: Note that you also have to set the ACLs correctly. See https://www.concurrency.com/blog/may-2019/key-based-authentication-for-openssh-on-windows.

Comment: Kurtis Rader's saying is really crucial!

Comment: I can't stress enough how _absolutely bonkers_ it is that changing file permissions is such a verbose operation on Windows

Comment: I had everything done but the powershell script... thanks!

Comment: This is `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on every other operating system...  alas this worked, thank you!

Comment: Wow.  I've been trying for several days (never mind exactly how many) to get this puppy to work, and ONLY this little script did the trick. Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: the script gives `Exception lors de l'appel de «SetAccessRule» avec «1» argument(s): «Impossible de traduire certaines ou toutes les références       
d'identité.»` You'll have to change `Administrators` to the appropriate string on your language version of Windows

Comment: You don't have to change permissions if you use `StrictModes no` in the sshd_config.

Comment: or, an easier way to change the permissions: ```icacls.exe "C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys" /inheritance:r /grant "Administrators:F" /grant "SYSTEM:F"```

Answer (score 1):

I was just struggling with this for approx two hours but what one was only mentioned as sidenote in [Martins Article](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#key_authentication) was finally the solution to me:

**Setting up SSH public key authentication**

Though, with the default Win32-OpenSSH configuration there is an exception set in sshd_config for accounts in Administrators group. For these, the server uses a different location for the authorized keys file: `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` (i.e. typically `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`).

So as my user is a member of the Administrators group all I had to do is move my `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `%PROGRAMDATA/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys`

BTW: I'm running Windows 11 Pro 22H2